# Time spent above 0 for time-changed càdlàg functions

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, continuity, skorohod-space

Let $\psi \in D([0,T],\mathbb R)$, the [Skorokhod space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g)  of real-valued càdlàg functions (right continuous with left limits) on $[0,T]$. Let $\Gamma$ be the set of time-changes  $\gamma$ that are continuous, increasing, $\gamma(0)=0$ and $\gamma(T)=T$. Is it true that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that if $\sup_{t\in[0,T]}|\gamma(t)-t|\le \delta$, then Lebesgue measure
$$
{\rm Leb} \Big( t\in[0,T]: \psi(\gamma(t))<0\le\psi(t) \Big)\le \epsilon\,\,\,?
$$
Comment: It is true for $\psi\in C[0,T]$ if ${\rm Leb}(t:\psi=0)=0$, as in that case let $\delta'$ such that ${\rm Leb}(t:|\psi|\le\delta')\le\epsilon$ and by uniform continuity select the $\delta$ so that $\sup_{t\in[0,T]}|\psi(\gamma(t))-\psi(t)|\le \delta'$. Then
$$
{\rm Leb} \Big( t\in[0,T]: \psi(\gamma(t))<0\le\psi(t) \Big)\le {\rm Leb} \Big( t\in[0,T]:  | \psi(t)|\le \delta' \Big).
$$
It is also true for step functions $\psi(t)=\sum_{n=0}^Na_n\mathbf1_{\{[t_n,t_{n+1})\}}(t)$, as if $\sup_{t\in[0,T]}|\gamma(t)-t|=\sup_{t\in[0,T]}|t-\gamma^{-1}(t)|\le \epsilon/(N-1)$, using 
$$
{\rm Leb} \Big( t\in[0,T]: \psi(\gamma(t))<0\le\psi(t) \Big)\le {\rm Leb} \Big( t\in[0,T]: \psi(\gamma(t))\neq \psi(t) \Big),
$$
and
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
\psi(t)-\psi(\gamma(t))%&=\sum_{n=0}^Na_n\mathbf1_{\{[t_n,t_{n+1})\}}(t)-\sum_{n=0}^Na_n\mathbf1_{\{[t_n,t_{n+1})\}}(\gamma(t)) \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^Na_n\mathbf1_{\{[t_n,t_{n+1})\}}(t)-\sum_{n=0}^Na_n\mathbf1_{\{[\gamma^{-1}(t_n),\gamma^{-1}(t_{n+1}))\}}(t)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^Na_n\left(\mathbf1_{\{[t_n,t_{n+1})\}}(t)-\mathbf1_{\{[\gamma^{-1}(t_n),\gamma^{-1}(t_{n+1}))\}}(t)\right)
\end{split}\end{equation}
we deduce that $(t:\psi(t)-\psi(\gamma(t))\neq 0)\subset \cup_1^{N-1} [\gamma^{-1}(t_n)\wedge t_n,\gamma^{-1}(t_n)\vee t_n]$, which Lebesgue measure is less than $\epsilon$. Of course this proof is of no use even for continuous $\psi$.